# Python 3 urllib.request capture and or stop redirection

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, urllib

So I am using the below code snippet to capture the URL request. The issue is when a redirect is happening I need a way to either capture that a redirect has happened and or just stop the redirection altogether. Right now when I print out the code I see a 200 as that is the code of the redirect page. Also a geturl() gives me the url of the redirected page as it should but doesn't help me with the redirect issue.

```
url = website + console
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=10, context=context)
code = response.getcode()
print(code)
print(response.geturl())
```

Answer (score -1):

So the best answer I found for this was to change the library I was using and go with Requests. It is very easy to set redirects to false and to accommodate for the ssh issues where you need to ignore them it is as simple as verify=false.

```
import requests    
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, allow_redirects=False, timeout=5)
```

Comment: I am getting this error
    AttributeError: __exit__